# How to upgrade Angular2 packages dependeces?

Tags: angular

I have an old angular2 project with the version 2.2.1 and I would like to upgrade the dependences to latest angular version 2.4.0

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.26"
  },
```

I is enough to change all strings "2.2.1" by "2.4.0" in "@angular/..." packages? Or I should do something to install latest or compatible version of all other packages like core-js, rxjs, etc ?

Comment: The router should be updated to 3.4.0. The other angular dependencies should be updated to the same version as the ones in angular 2.4.0's package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

You run a quick update for all packages and update the package.json file with updated versions, Follow these steps

1. Delete the **node_modules** folder.
2. Delete npm-cache from C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming
3. Open command prompt and navigate to root folder of your application.
4. Check for the updates in npm packages using the command

   ```
   npm-check-updates -u
   ```
5. Update all the packages and modify your package.json to current version using the command

   ```
   npm update --save
   ```

Also, update the npm packages globally using the command

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Hope this must fix your problem, if not let me know.