# Command to Upgrade safely from ngrx v2.0 to 4.0

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, ngrx, ngrx-store

Is there a command to upgrade from `ngrx v-2` to `ngrx v4` like we had for Angular version 2.0 to version 4.0 ?

I tried searching for one but the only thing i got in the git repo as well as other blogs is this `npm install @ngrx/core @ngrx/store --save`.

I know i can uninstall ngrx v2.0 and then run this command . But is there any other way to do it directly . I am using angular cli.

My present ngrx dependencies.

I want to Update all of these to latest v4.

[image: NGRX]

Comment: Nop, there is no such thing. Consider that the version 4.0.0 introduces breaking changes, so there is no guaranties that your application wont be broken if you update the dependencies

Comment: You need yo change your application also, have a look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)

Comment: @AdrianFaciu thanks but i know about all of these, i have recently build a app from scratch in ngrx 4. But i have a app that eas build on ngrx 2 in wanted to refractor it and updage the dependencies, guess have to delete it from npm nd reinstall

Comment: @RahulSingh if you are updating to `2.x` to `4.0` you need to change a lot, as they removed `payload` property

Comment: @Aravind i know that and i have taken care of it but a command would have been better it depends upon the user

Comment: A simple way is to delete these dependencies from `package.json` and from the `node_modules` use `npm i --save packages`. Or refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881051/how-to-upgrade-angular2-packages-dependeces/42881188#42881188)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NPM package `npm-check-updates` for this. [[link]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)